# Toss a fair coin untill both a head and tail have appeared at least once, what is the probability that three tosses will be required?

Tags: statistics

Sample space is (HT, TH, HHT, TTH, HHHT, TTTH,.....)
I thought that since the outcome of each toss is independent of the previous toss the probabillity that it takes exactly 3 tosses (HHT, TTH) is simply equal to 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5 = 1/4

Comment: Do you mean exactly 3 tosses, or at least 3 tosses?

Comment: Exactly 3 tosses

Comment: This is the correct answer, with the correct reasoning, for the probability that *exactly* three tosses will be required. That I think is the most natural interpretation of the question. But if we interpret the question to mean *at least* three tosses will be required, the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it suffices to look at the sample space of 3 tosses, which has 8 elements.  The only two possibilites which require exactly 3 tosses are HHT and TTH.  Any possibility with starts with HT or TH only requires 2 tosses while HHH and TTT require more that 3 tosses.  So the probability is 2/8 or 1/4.